# Looping in a particular range of numbers in prime ng- input number spinner

Tags: angular, primeng, rxjs-observables

How to loop through a range of numbers for example: 0 to 10, in prime ng input number spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p-inputNumber [showButtons]="true"  formControlName="timeHour"  [step]='1' [size]='2' value="12">
</p-inputNumber>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  myForm = new FormGroup({
  timeHour: new FormControl(12)
  });
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.spinnerChange();
    }
  spinnerChange(): void{

    this.myForm.get('timeHour').valueChanges
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
     )
    .subscribe(x => {
      const valueChangedHour = x < 1 ? 12 :
      (x > 12 ? 1 : x);
      this.myForm.patchValue({
        timeHour : valueChangedHour
      });
      });
    
   

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    // Now let's also unsubscribe from the subject itself:
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```